# Ognl expression is not working in 'list' attribute of select tag while it is working fine in 'name' attribute

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, ognl

```
<s:select
name="%{#attr.addressBeanList}.%{#attr.address}.addressCopyFrom"
listKey="value" listValue="label"
list="%{#attr.addressBeanList}.%{#attr.address}.addressCopyFromDropDown">
</s:select>
```

Error:

> ognl expression in 'list' attribute is not evaluating while it is being treated as string literal.
>
> The requested list **key '%{#attr.addressBeanList}.%{#attr.address}.addressCopyFromDropDown'** could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

Comment: Without knowing what the actual data is it's difficult to guess--but `list` is supposed to be... well, a list, like `addressBeanList`. But who knows? What's your data? What list are you attempting to select from?

Comment: @Dave Newton  this snippet is from child jsp and it is inserted on some other jsp. addressBeanList and address are imported from parent jsp and their type is string in tiles:putAttribute. addressCopyFromDropDown is a type of ArrayList. as i mentioned earlier it is working in 'name' attribute but no luck for list. while debugging i noticed that it evaluates whole string that is on parent jsp. but there is no list.

Comment: Hi, I also encounter Ognl expression is not working in 'list' when pass as attribute in radio tag. We are doing migration from struts 2.3.x to struts 2.5.x. And the code <s:radio id="%{#attr.id}" name="%{#attr.name}" list="%{(#attr.ognlExpression)(#attr)}" onclick="%{#attr.onclick}" /> ..value of ognlExpression="#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}" from parent jsp passed as attribute .This is working before then after migration it is not working anymore. Did your problem resolved before? please share the solution. Thanks